# TensorFlow: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have the following code which uses TensorFlow. After I reshape a list, it says

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

when I try to print its shape.

```
# Get the shape of the training data.
print "train_data.shape: " + str(train_data.shape)
train_data = tf.reshape(train_data, [400, 1])
print "train_data.shape: " + str(train_data.shape)
train_size,num_features = train_data.shape
```

Output:

> train_data.shape: (400,) 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 1, in    File
>   "/home/shehab/Downloads/tools/python/pycharm-edu-2.0.4/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py",
>   line 21, in do_import
>       module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/shehab/Dropbox/py-projects/try-tf/logistic_regression.py", line
>   77, in 
>       print "train_data.shape: " + str(train_data.shape) AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'shape'

Could anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since TensorFlow 1.0, `tf.Tensor` now has a [`tf.Tensor.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#shape) property, which returns the same value as [`tf.Tensor.get_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#get_shape).

---

Indeed, in versions prior to TensorFlow 1.0 `tf.Tensor` doesn't have a `.shape` property. You should use the `Tensor.get_shape()` method instead:

```
train_data = tf.reshape(train_data, [400, 1])
print "train_data.shape: " + str(train_data.get_shape())
```

Note that in general you might not be able to get the actual shape of the result of a TensorFlow operation. In some cases, the shape will be a computed value that depends on running the computation to find its value; and it may even vary from one run to the next (e.g. the shape of [`tf.unique()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#unique)). In that case, the result of `get_shape()` for some dimensions may be `None` (or `"?"`).

Comment: Then how 'print "train_data.shape: " + str(train_data.shape)' is outputting 'train_data.shape: (400,)'?

Comment: I assume the first `train_data.shape` is a NumPy array. After you reassign the result of `tf.reshape()` to `train_data` its type is a `tf.Tensor`.

Comment: In APIr.1.0 there is `shape` attribute for `tf.Tensor`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#shape

Comment: @tuned Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @mrry calling Tensorobject.shape for placeholders would return None as the dimension, I saw somewhere you answered calling tf.shape may help, but it will return a tensor. Isn't there any way that tf.shape returns list of integers? I have to mention that I don't want to run eval or run.

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and replace `train_data.shape` with `tf.Session.run(tf.rank(train_data))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.shape(tensor)`, or `tf.get_shape(tensor)`.