# How to convert Tensor into NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I have trained `ResNet50` model on my data. I want to get the output of a custom layer while making the prediction. I tried using the below code to get the output of a custom layer, it gives data in a tensor format, but I need the data in a `NumPy array` format. I tried to convert the tensor to NumPy array but getting errors, I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow), but it wasn't helpful

Can anyone share some thoughts, any advice will be very helpful

```
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.Session(config=config)

model = load_model(model_path) # load trained model

data = load_data(data_path) # load data for predictions
result = model.predict(data)
print(type(result_dev))
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 

result = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
print(type(result))
#<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

Things I tried

#### Option 1

```
result = result.numpy()
```

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

#### Option 2

```
result = result.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

> 2020-09-22 11:21:59.522138: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:983] successful
> NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
> at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2020-09-22
> 11:21:59.522343: I
> tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1618] Found device 0
> with properties:

Dependency Installed:

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally approach mentioned [here](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction) worked for me with `tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0` and `keras==2.2.4`

Answer (score 0):

You can only convert tensors to numpy arrays during Eager execution. Since you're using a version older than 2.0 this is not enabled by default.

In any case, you can call this after importing tensorflow:

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
```

Depending on your framework and usecase, you might also have to run `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly` (if you have `tf.function` defined anywhere). For better support of the Eager mode, you should upgrade tensorflow to the newest version and use `tf.keras` as your code might not work properly with older standalone versions of `Keras`. In newer versions, you can specify your keras model to run eagerly like this:

```
model.run_eagerly = True
```

Comment: I tried enabling eager excecution with `tf.enable_eager_execution()` but it throws error `RuntimeError: get_session is not available when TensorFlow is executing eagerly.`. I have also tried `tensorflow-gpu==2.0` but as model was trained on `tensorflow-gpu==1.15` its throwing error while loading it with `tensorflow-gpu==2.0`

Comment: I was expecting this, hence my warning. Compatibility in these older versions is tricky (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/367)) and I won't be able to directly help you with that as it is very project-specific and requires some trial and error until you find the correct package combinations. In any case, my answer stands: If you want to use Eager, this is how you go about it generally.

Answer (score 0):

A `tensor` can be converted into a `numpy` array using following function of `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.make_ndarray(
    tensor
)
```

For example:

```
# Tensor a has shape (2,3)
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
proto_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(a)  # convert `tensor a` to a proto tensor
tf.make_ndarray(proto_tensor) # output: array([[1, 2, 3],
#                                              [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
# output has shape (2,3)
```

Comment: `tf.make_ndarray(tensor)` throws this error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'`

Comment: Check this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666116/14191955

Comment: How does the above link help solve the problem which OP has?